# Python plotly order facet_wrap by specific facet

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a simple facet_wrap barplot generated in python plotly that looks like the attached image.

Is it possible to order the x-axis to another facet than the last one. The pandas dataframe is sorted according to the y-axis (which is what I want) but would like this specifically on second-to-last facet (so that it looks similar to the last one in the current plot) but keep the current order of the facet.  [simple facet_wrap barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUzPf.png)

Sample code below. This will automatically sort the x-axis according to the bottom facet - which is "DEN_Tumour_WD" in this case.

```py
toPlot = pd.DataFrame(allModel)
toPlot = toPlot.sort_values(by=['Flux Ratio (log-scaled)'])

fig = px.bar(toPlot,
             x='Reaction',
             y='Flux Ratio (log-scaled)',
             template = 'none',
             facet_row="Model",
             color='Subsystem',
             category_orders={"Model": ["nonDEN_Liver_CD",
                                        "nonDEN_Liver_WD",
                                        "DEN_Liver_CD",
                                        "DEN_AdjLiver_WD",
                                        "DEN_Tumour_WD"]})
```

Comment: Could you please share your code, so we can see what have you tried.

Comment: This might rather be a problem with sorting the pandas df, however, the df should be sorted by 'Flux Ratio' to be correct on the y-axis